# Code Contracts: How do I supply a contract class for a generic interface?

Tags: .net, generics, interface, code-contracts

I'd like to specify a contract for this generic interface, using Code Contracts:

```
interface IRandomWriteAccessible<T>
{
    T this[uint index] { set; }
    uint Length { get; }
}
```

The documentation says to use the `ContractClass` attribute when specifying a contract for an interface. However, the compiler will complain about this:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(IRandomWriteAccessibleContract<T>))]
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     <-- compiler error
interface IRandomWriteAccessible<T> { … }

[ContractClassFor(typeof(IRandomWriteAccessible<T>))]
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          <-- compiler error
sealed class IRandomWriteAccessibleContract<T> : IRandomWriteAccessible<T> { … }
```

It seems that type parameters cannot be used with attributes.

How *do* I write a contract for my generic interface? Or is this not possible with Code Contracts?

Comment: I have not verified this, but remove the `T` from your attribute usage as follows: `[ContractClass(typeof(IRandomWriteAccessibleContract<>))]`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As mentioned by other comments in this question, you should remove the generic type identifier from your attribute usage as it can not be resolved at compile time:

```
[ContractClass(typeof(IRandomWriteAccessibleContract<>))]
```

Comment: I looked this up in the C# language specification out of curiosity: The relevant chapters are _14.5.11 (typeof operator)_ and _25.5 (generics: constructed types)_, if anyone else is interested.

Comment: Also, if the generic class you're typeof()'ing takes more than one parameter, you have to use commas; for instance, typeof(YourType<,>), where YourType takes two type parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, but you can see the technical reasons behind this limitation, right?

The reason that you can't specify the ContractClass is because `Blah<T>` is not a class.

If you can make an interface for a concrete class by specifying a value for `T`, even though I'm sure this is sub-optimal.