# Code Contracts: ContractClassFor when dealing with a generic abstract class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, code-contracts

So, I have a little problem here.

Suppose I have:

```
public class Repository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    public abstract void Add(TEntity entity);

    // ...and so on...
}
```

And now I want to define a contract class, like so:

```
public class RepositoryContracts<TEntity> : Repository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        Contract.Requires(entity != null);
    }

    // ...etc...
}
```

Now, I'd have to mark these classes with ContractClassAttribute and ContractClassForAttribute. Problem being, this won't work:

```
[ContractClassFor(typeof(Repository<TEntity>))] // what is TEntity?! error!
```

So, the question boils down to: How do I link these two classes together using those attributes, when they're generic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150983/code-contracts-is-it-possible-to-supply-a-contract-class-for-a-generic-interface), kinda.

The typeof(Repository<>) syntax didn't seem to work for me, but turns out, typeof(Repository<,>) does the trick, since there are two type parameters.

Closing the question, and adding a comment to [the previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150983/code-contracts-is-it-possible-to-supply-a-contract-class-for-a-generic-interface).

Comment: I am having the same issue, removing the generic `TEntity` solved it but when i `implement` this `interface` on some other `class`, it complaints that `class` or `interface` does not implement IRepository methods. Any ideas ?