# Java type casting and scope

Tags: java

I have two interfaces: MinServer and MaxServer. MaxServer extends MinServer. So, is the following code normal and right?

```
MinServer server=foo.getUndefinedServer();
...code according to MinServer
if (isThisServerMax){
  server=(MaxServer)server;
...code according to MaxServer
}
...code according to MinServer
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't understand. Your reminds me of typical examples of LSP violations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861107/liskov-substitution-principle-vehicle-example though

Comment: @zapl I have a client, that can connect either to remote server with minimum rights or to local server with maximum rights. The server type is taken from configuration. So in code I want to use this approach. If it's min it do minimum, otherwise maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not correct.

At this point:

```
server=(MaxServer)server
...code according to MaxServer
```

You are casting a MaxServer to a MinServer (which is OK) but then you assign the result of the casting to a MinServer ... so ehhm, you are in the same point where you started.

If you change it like this:

```
MaxServer server2 = (MaxServer)server
...code according to MaxServer using server2
```

then it will be correct.

Comment: Maybe you wanted so say "You are casting a MinServer to a MaxServer which is ok"?

Comment: @PashaTurok No, I wanted to say it as it is there. It is OK to do the cast at that point as he has already validated with that `if` that the cast will not throw an exception.

Comment: Then I don't understand you. We are casting MinServer to MaxServer. I think so.

Comment: @PashaTurok You cast from `Min` to `Max`, and then you assign it to the variable `server` which is a `Min` so you are again where you started.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If the `isThisServerMax` is a `boolean` variable that correctly indicates whether `server`'s class implements `MaxServer`, then everything actually shown will run without error.  However, nothing you present establishes a context wherein methods can be invoked on `server` that do not belong to interface `MinServer`, as I suppose is the intended meaning of "code according to MaxServer".

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the downcast you are doing. It will compile fine. Just know that if it can't be downcasted it will throw a runtime exception that you should handle. If it is not actually a MaxServer then it will throw an error...